# How to set indices of a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a data frame j_2 which has many columns amongst which are 'city' and 'state'.

I have to create a new data frame from it but I'm not exactly sure what is being asked of me.

"From j_2 create a new data frame 'j_3' where state and city are set as indices of j_2"

I'm not sure what it means to set them as indices.

Comment: `j_2.set_index(['state', 'city'])`

Answer (score 0):

In pandas a dataframe has indices (row names) and columns (column names). Question is asking you to create a dataframe j_3 using existing dataframe j_2. Then use the  **state** and **city** as indices (row names) of your j_3 data frame. Here is how to do it in one step.

```
j_3 = j_2.copy().set_index(['state', 'city'])
```

Note: Consider accepting this comment as selected answer if it solves your purpose.